# Multiple Server-client SCP File transfer

Tags: java, networking, file-io, scp

I am Using a server to send a file to multiple clients using  SCP Program to send a file.
During uploading the file,in intermediate it shows the below exception.But both the Server and client is pinging.(Sometimes it is uploading successfully,but sometimes it shows exception)

SCP Program:JSch: SCP a File in Java

Do not know when this exception occurs

```
Exception in thread "Exec thread 117.97.213.116"    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSession.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(thread.java)
```

Kindly advice me to solve the issue.

Regards
Prakash